# Trying to populate dropdown using the result of mongo query

Tags: mongodb, variables, azure-cosmosdb, grafana

I have created a grafana application. I am using the variables function and within that, I have the option to return a query which populates the dropdown. I have tested the query in a normal table panel and it returns the correct values. Using this in the query in the variables section doesn't work.

Additionally and potentially more importantly, since mongo is not used by default as a datasource for Grafana, I have to install a plugin which is linked:

https://github.com/JamesOsgood/mongodb-grafana

What would be the best way to achieve what I am doing? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of trying, turns out the time range seemed to be discombobulating things. After removing it, the dropdown worked fine displaying the results I needed. The time wasn't a critical aspect of the task, just desired behaviour. In either case, my problem was solved. Have a similar issue? Give it a try, remove the `$from` and `$to` in your `$match`